# I am unable to on hotspot

Tags: networking

I am unable to on my pc's hotspot it is showing "we can't share this internet connection because we can't connect to cellular network". and i am using internet via dongle in PC
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your windows 10 have old build this maybe bugs or something Try to update your windows 10 or join insider program